# Application can't find app.config file when run at Windows Startup

Tags: c#, setup-project

Recently, I added a setup project to my application. In the setup project, I added a registry value that would start my application at windows startup to the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run key. When the application runs from this location, it crashes with a System.NullReference exception (it can't find my app.config file, which gets read in a method when the app loads up). I can run the application perfectly fine from the start menu, or from the installed folder. How can I get my application to run at Startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that will be running with the system folder as the working folder. Either putting the config file in the system folder or ensuring the working folder is set should fix the problem.

Comment: How would I set the working folder in the Registry Key? Would I need to do that in the Setup project?

Comment: I got it...I check Environment.CurrentDirectory on the app's startup, and if it contains system32, then I set it to the Application.StartupPath. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a note...I also had to check and see if the Environment.CurrentDirectory contained syswow64 for a 64bit os...

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I know this is an old question but the solution is kind of lacking clarity in my opinion. I had the same issue and you don't have to put the app.config (your.exe.config) into the system folder. If you want to keep your program portable and without an MSI you can simply put some lines into the form.

```
APP_PATH = Application.ExecutablePath.ToString();
Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(APP_PATH);
```

Do this early in your form class and it will work.